# Spring Data JPA - Left Join with Multiple Criteria

Tags: sql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

I need to do a join using a `JOIN TABLE ON ... AND ...` using Spring Data JPA criteria builder.

I know I can do a basic join like so:

```
Join<ReportEntity, ProductEntity> productJoin = root.join("products", JoinType.LEFT);
```

But can I specify extra criteria for the join? If not, is there another way to achieve this using the Criteria Builder? This is the SQL query I'd like to reproduce:

```
SELECT r.id, p.rare
FROM REPORT r
LEFT JOIN PRODUCT p
     ON r.id = p.report_id AND p.rare = 1
WHERE p.report_id IS NULL;
```

Note that specifying `p.rare = 1` in the above query in the `WHERE` clause does not give the desired result, it needs to go in the `ON` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Join<ReportEntity, ProductEntity> productJoin = root.join("products", JoinType.LEFT);

Predicate joinPredicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("id"), productJoin.get("reportId"));
Predicate rarePredicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(productJoin.get("rare"), 1);

productJoin.on(joinPredicate, rarePredicate);
```